# Maintain session value in Xunit .net core 3.1

Tags: xunit.net, .net-core-3.1

I am writing a Unit test case for one method which contains **session** and **tempdata** both.
In my scenario, I am debugging below code

```
[Fact]
        public async Task OnGet_AssosiateUserNotFoundWithGivenId()
        {
            MockParamsForVerifyUserIdentityModelTest(out var mockUserManager, out var mockEventLogClient, out var mockPageMessageManager,
                out var mockLogger, out var mockGAClient, out var mockEmailSender,
                out var mockUserService, out var mockConfiguration, out var pageContext);

            mockUserManager.Setup(m => m.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser());

            var pageModel = new VerifyUserIdentityModel(null, null, null, null, null, null)
            {
                PageContext = pageContext
            };
            
            pageModel.ModelState.AddModelError("error", "some error");

            var result = await pageModel.OnGetAsync("abc");

            Assert.IsType<PageResult>(result);

        }
```

and when it goes to actual **OnGet** method in PageModel and trying to set Value in Tempdata it's throwing error as below

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In my action i have written below code

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            id = TempData.Peek("UserId").ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["UserId"] = id;
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("hitcount") == null)
        {
            currentHitCount = 1;
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("hitcount", currentHitCount);
        }
```

Please help me in working things right like How can i set **Session** value from test case and why tempdata is throwing error.

Thanks in Advance,
Jitendra